# What is a good hosted email service?

Tags: email, email-server, hosted

I am looking for a hosted email service for a handful of email accounts. It needs to be very reliable and provide a nice web mail interface. I would like an admin where I can manage accounts. I've used Communigate before, it's functional but ugly. Exchange web mail is feature rich enough, but isn't as performant as the later two contestants.

I am currently paying $50/yearly for hosted Gmail through Google. The features of the web email client are fine for personal use, but not flexible enough for professional use. The administration tools also suck.

In short, I want a hosted service with a better experience than gmail or Communigate but is still speedy.

Comment: You may want to list what sort of features you need that Google can't offer you.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider a hosted Zimbra or Exchange solution. I haven't found Exchange to perform poorly via webmail, but Zimbra is certainly an option. [01.com](http://www.01.com) is the provider my company used to use before moving to Exchange internally. The administration console in Zimbra is very comprehensive and may be close to what you're looking for.